# Display Checkbox List Text

Tags: reactjs

I have an array data and I am trying to display the checkbox list with the array. It only shows three empty check boxes. The label does not show text. What am I wrong with my code?

```
    const campusData = [
  { id: 1, value:'A',name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, value:'B',name: 'B' },
  { id: 3, value:'C',name: 'C' }
]

...
render(){
 return (
      <div>
       {campusData.map(item =>
       <input type="checkbox"  key={item.id} {...item} label={item.name} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} /> 
      )
       }
       </div>   
      )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input hasn't `label` attribute

try like this.

**Method 1**

```
...
render(){
   return (
       <div>
       {
          campusData.map(item => (
            <label>
               <input type="checkbox"  key={item.id} {...item} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} />
               {item.name}
            </label>
          ))
       }
       </div>   
   );
}
...
```

***CSS***

```
label {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:10px;
 margin:0 0 10px;
 display:block; 
}

label:hover {
 background:#eee;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

**Method 2**
Use the for attribute (match the checkbox id):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value">
<label for="checkbox_id">Text</label>
```

NOTE: ID must be unique on the page!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with `<label>`

```
<label>
  {item.name}
  <input type="checkbox"  key={item.id} {...item} label={item.name} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not told it to display any text, assuming this is a standard HTMLInputElement.

There is no property 'label', you have to wrap your input in a label (or use the for attribute on the label).

```
const campusData = [
  { id: 1, value:'A',name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, value:'B',name: 'B' },
  { id: 3, value:'C',name: 'C' }
]

...
render(){
 return (
     <div>
        {campusData.map( item => 
            <label>
                {item.name}
                <input type="checkbox"  key={item.id} {...item} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} /> 
            </label>
        )}
     </div>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

input hasn't `label` attribute

try like this.

```
...
render(){
   return (
       <div>
       {
          campusData.map(item => (
            <label>
               <input type="checkbox"  key={item.id} {...item} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} />
               {item.name}
            </label>
          ))
       }
       </div>   
   );
}
...
```

***CSS***

```
label {
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:10px;
 margin:0 0 10px;
 display:block; 
}

label:hover {
 background:#eee;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```